# JS - FortuneWheel

Tags: javascript, html, css, canvas, 2d

I want to develop a kind of wheel of fortune with javascript. I want to define both the output and the start. If the user turns the wheel with a minimum speed, the wheel should rotate a few times depending on the rotation speed, before it stops on the desired field.

So far I have only been able to implement the basics, but I hope that somebody can help me to implement the complete process, since I can't get any further now.

> HOW TO MAKE WHEEL ROTATING A SERVERAL TIMES ENDING WITH THE targetAngle ?

```js
let element = document.getElementById("wheel");
let region = new ZingTouch.Region(element);

let currentAngle = 0, // this is the current angle of the wheel by the rotate gesture
  targetAngle = 0; // blue field is the target where the wheel should stop
let minimumAngle = 30, // minimumAngle to make the wheel spinning
  rotatedAngle = 0, // total spinned angle of the wheel by the rotate gesture
  spinning = false

setInterval(() => {
  rotatedAngle = 0;
}, 200)

region.bind(element, 'rotate', function(e) {
  if (rotatedAngle > minimumAngle && rotatedAngle > 180) {
    spinning = true;
    document.getElementById("spinning").innerHTML = "spinning = true"
    // HOW TO MAKE WHEEL ROTATING A SERVERAL TIMES ENDING WITH THE targetAngle ? 
  } else if (!spinning) {
    currentAngle += e.detail.distanceFromLast;
    rotatedAngle += e.detail.distanceFromLast;
    element.style.transform = 'rotate(' + currentAngle + 'deg)';
  }
})
```

```css
#wheel {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: auto;
  width: 20%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/zingtouch/1.0.6/zingtouch.min.js"></script>
<img id="wheel" src="https://reel-mkt.com/templates/fortune_reel_lp/img/wheel.png">
<p id="spinning">spinning = false</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is how I would do it:

1. I need an event like `"click"` to begin spinning
2. I'm calculating the `targetAngle` as a random angle: `targetAngle = currentAngle + Math.random() * 360 + minimumAngle;`
3. I'm using `requestAnimationFrame` for the animation.
4. I'm calculating the speed as 1/10 of the distance between the `targetAngle` and the  `currentAngle`
5. I'm not using `ZingTouch` as you intended; I don't use the `rotatedAngle` either.

I hope this is what you need.

```js
let element = document.getElementById("wheel");
/*let region = new ZingTouch.Region(element);*/

let currentAngle = 0, // this is the current angle of the wheel by the rotate gesture
  targetAngle = 0; // blue field is the target where the wheel should stop
let minimumAngle = 30, // minimumAngle to make the wheel spinning
  //rotatedAngle = 0, // total spinned angle of the wheel by the rotate gesture
  spinning = false;

let rid = null;

element.addEventListener("click", () => {
  targetAngle = currentAngle + Math.random() * 360 + minimumAngle;

  if (spinning) {
    spinning = false;
     if (rid) {
      cancelAnimationFrame(rid);
      rid = null;
    }
  } else {   
    spinning = true;
    Animation();
  }
  
  is_spinning.innerHTML = spinning;
});

function Animation() {
  rid = requestAnimationFrame(Animation);
  if (currentAngle <= targetAngle) {
    let speed = (targetAngle - currentAngle)/10;
    currentAngle += speed;
    element.style.transform = `rotate(${currentAngle}deg)`;
        if(speed <= 1){// if the speed is < 1 stop the wheel
          cancelAnimationFrame(rid);
          spinning = false;
        }
    
  } else {//stop the wheel
    cancelAnimationFrame(rid);
    spinning = false;
  }
  
  is_spinning.innerHTML = spinning;
}
```

```css
#wheel {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: auto;
  width: 20%;
}
```

```html
<img id="wheel" src="https://reel-mkt.com/templates/fortune_reel_lp/img/wheel.png">
<p>spinning = <span  id="is_spinning">false</span></p>
```

**An observation"": Your question is tagged as `canvas` but in your code you positioned the image in the center of the screen. So I assumed that you wanted to rotate the image.

Comment: I do not want to use an Click event I want to implement ZingTouch and calutate the spinning rotation by the gesture speed. Also i want the Wheel to be rotated multiple times before it stops. Thanks for your answer but this is not really what I‘d liked to get. :(